# list all files in firebase storage v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am developing a page and am using firebase storage as the file storage. I tried using the given codes in the firebase developer docs but I can't seem to make it work. What could be the problem?

```
document.getElementById("but").addEventListener('click', e => {

    // Create a reference under which you want to list
    const listRef = ref(storage, 'folder/');
    // Find all the prefixes and items.
    listAll(listRef)
        .then((res) => {
            res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
                // All the prefixes under listRef.
                // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
            });
            res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
                // All the items under listRef.
                console.log( getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `folder/${itemRef}`)))
            })
        })
});
```

Comment: Please read the Firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?#web-version-9_1

Comment: "I can't seem to make it work" What doesn't work about the code you shared? If there's an error, please share the error message and stack trace in your question. If there's no error, set breakpoints on every line and run the code in a debugger. Which line is the first one that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what problem you have with the code, but one mistake is in :

```
res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
    // All the items under listRef.
    console.log( getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `folder/${itemRef}`)))
})
```

The `getDownloadURL` function performs an asynchronous call to the server, so you'll need to either use `await` or `then` to capture that result:

```
res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `folder/${itemRef}`))
        .then((downloadURL) => {
            console.log(downloadURL);
        });
})
```